# python read serial output from arduino

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port

I have an Arduino hooked up with 2 `DS18B20` temp sensors. I'm very (VERY) new to python. I am looking for a way to read the serial input and parse it into a sqlite database, but that is getting ahead of myself. Why do I get an error while trying to define my serial port to a variable?

First things first `sys.version`

```
2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)]
```

My current, just read input from the serial connection program.

```
from serial import serial
import time


# open serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem621',9600,timeout=2) 
ser.open()


while True:
    print('dev 0' + ser.read())     
    pass

ser.close()
```

I can not currently get it to compile. Most of the results I've found for this error tell to add `from serial import serial`, but in this case it hasn't worked.

The error.

```
$ python ser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ser.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serial import serial
  File "/Users/frankwiebenga/serial.py", line 8, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Also if I just use `import serial` I get the same error

```
$ python ser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ser.py", line 1, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/Users/frankwiebenga/serial.py", line 8, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Also, per comment. Created new file named `something.py` and still get the same error regardless of using `import serial` or `from serial import serial`.

```
$ python something.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "something.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serial import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
```

When running my bash script I get an output that is valid, so I know it isn't the Arduino code.

Output:

```
Requesting temperatures...DONE
Device 0: 25.62
Device 1: 25.75
Requesting temperatures...DONE
Device 0: 25.62
Device 1: 25.81
```

Bash:

```
while true  # loop forever
do
   inputline="" # clear input

   # Loop until we get a valid reading from AVR
   until inputline=$(echo $inputline | grep -e "^temp: ")
   do
      inputline=$(head -n 1 < /dev/tty.usbmodem621)
   done
   echo "$inputline"
done
```

Comment: Your script is named serial.py, which is confusing things when you do import serial.  Rename your script to something else.

Comment: @atrueresistance, it sounds like you just created a new file named something.py rather than renaming the serial.py to something.py. You will have to rename or remove the script with the name serial.py.

Comment: @atrueresistance, you have to both do the renaming, and use the proper import command `import serial`.  Your updated error has `from serial import serial`, which uses the wrong case for `Serial`.  As dkamins mentions, use either `import serial` or `from serial import Serial`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `import serial`. `serial` is the name of the module and it does not contain an attribute with name `serial`.

http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports

Answer (score 2):

You can EITHER do:

```
from serial import Serial

s = Serial(...)
```

OR:

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial(...)
```

Choose one.

Answer (score -1):

You need do `pip install pyserial` instead of `pip install serial` (which does not run into an error but installs another module).